# Javascript RegEx for matching positive and negative integers

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, typescript

I am trying to extract **positive** and **negative integers** from the given string. But able to extract only positive integers.

I am passing `"34,-10"` string into `getNumbersFromString` param

**I am getting**

**Output:**

```
['34','10']
```

**The expected output should be**

```
[34,-10]
```

How do I solve this problem?

```js
function getNumbersFromString(numberString){
  var regx = numberString.match(/\d+/g);
  return regx;
}

console.log(getNumbersFromString("34,-10"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also match the `-`sign(at least `0` and at most `1`) before the number. Then you can use `map()` to convert them to number.

```js
function getNumbersFromString(numberString){
  var regx = numberString.match(/-?\d+/g).map(Number);
  return regx;
}

console.log(getNumbersFromString("34,-10"));
```

Comment: Negative should be optional -?

Comment: you answers is right but i am expecting non string values in array example [34,-10]

Comment: Can the downvoter pelase explain the reason.

Comment: This is better cause worked for me : `num.match(/-?\d+/g).join('')`

Answer (score 2):

You should use regex with conditional `-` symbol like that `/-?\d+/`, also you should convert string to number with e.g `parseInt` function.

Answer (score 2):

Why use an regex here. What about split() and map()

```js
function getNumbersFromString(numberString){
  return numberString.split(',').map(Number)
}

console.log(getNumbersFromString("34,-10"));
```

Or is the input string not "clean" and contains also text?

Answer (score 0):

Non `regex` version (assuming input strings are proper csv):

```js
function getNumbersFromString(numberString){
  return numberString.split(',').map(v => parseInt(v))
}

console.log(getNumbersFromString("34,-10"))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### RegEx:

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/VvnpVC/1) might help you to pass integers using a list of chars:

- numbers 0-9
- <kbd>+</kbd>
- <kbd>-</kbd>

---

```
[+\-0-9]+
```

If you wish, you can wrap it with a capturing group, just to be simple for string replace using a `$1`:

```
([+\-0-9]+)
```

[image]

#### Graph:

This graph shows how the expression works:

[image]

#### Code:

```js
function getNumbersFromString(numberString){
  var regex = numberString.match(/[+\-0-9]+/g);
  return regex;
}

console.log(getNumbersFromString("34, -10, +10, +34"));
```